# Doctrine Insert - one to one relation without getting reference_id

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework3

I have two entities named user and user_authentication. They define a unidirectional relation. Relation type is one to one. Means, users entity has one to one relation with user authentication entity.

Doctrine entities are displayed below

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
*/
class User {

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=40, nullable=false)
 */
private $firstName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=40, nullable=true)
 */
private $lastName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="string", nullable=false)
 */
private $gender;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="availability", type="string", nullable=false)
 */
private $availability;


/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\User\Entity\UsersAuthentication", mappedBy="User", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
 */
protected $authentication;


}
```

AND

```
/**
 * UsersAuthentication
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users_authentication")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class UsersAuthentication {

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $userId;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $phone;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="token", type="string", length=128, nullable=false)
 */
private $token;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", nullable=false)
 */
private $type;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="last_login", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $lastLogin;

}
```

I want to insert data in user and user_authentication in one go. For example as explained in code below, but its not working.

```
    // Create new User entity.
    $user = new User();
    (isset($data->firstName))?$user->setFirstName($data->firstName):'';
    (isset($data->lastName))?$user->setLastName($data->lastName):'';
    (isset($data->gender))?$user->setGender($data->gender):'';        
    (isset($data->availability))?$user->setAvailability($data->availability):'';


    $userAuthEntity = new UsersAuthentication(); 
    $userAuthEntity->setLastLogin($date);
    (isset($data->email))?$userAuthEntity->setEmail($data->email):'';
    (isset($data->password))?$userAuthEntity->setPassword($data->password):'';
    (isset($data->phone))?$userAuthEntity->setPhone($data->phone):'';
    (isset($data->type))?$userAuthEntity->setType($data->type):'';
    $user->addAuthentication($userAuthEntity);

    $this->entityManager->persist($user);
    $this->entityManager->flush();
```

It's giving me following error: 
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null

Is it even possible which I am trying to do.

===================================================

After reading @rKeet and @zen answers I've added bidirectional mapping as suggested by @rKeet and update my addUser code to following and it worked. Kudos.

```
    $user = new User();
    $user->setFirstName($data->firstName) : '';
    $user->setLastName($data->lastName) : '';
    $user->setGender($data->gender) : '';
    $user->setAvailability($data->availability) : '';


    $UA = new UsersAuthentication();
    $UA->setActive(1);
    $UA->setCreatedDate($date);
    $UA->setEmail($data->email);
    $UA->setModifiedDate($date);
    $UA->setPassword($this->authManager->generate_hash($data->password));
    $UA->setPhone($data->phone);
    $UA->setType($data->type);
    $UA->setUser($user);

    $user->setAuthentication($UA);
    $this->entityManager->persist($user);
    $this->entityManager->flush();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're currently doing is setting up a [bi-directional OneToOne](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional) relation in a way that looks like [uni-directional](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional) but isn't either.

The "owner" property, on the `User` object is the one holing the reference to the `Authentication` object. You've defined it this way by setting it up that the `User` holds the column in the database.

You also want to create both records at the same time. With that, [zen's asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51901302/1155833) is correct: you must allow it to cascade persist. I'm assuming that you also want to remove the authentication in the event the user is removed, so you must also cascade persist. (It's a OneToOne after all).

Thus, then setting it up you would have this on the User side:

```
/**
 * @var Authentcation
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\User\Entity\UsersAuthentication", inversedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
 */
protected $authentication;
```

On the Authentication side you would have:

```
/**
 * @var User
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\User\Entity\User", mappedBy="authentication", nullable=false)
 */
protected $user;
```

Notice:

- The owner side has the `inversedBy` instead of the `mappedBy` (parent / child kind of thing - important! [Read up here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/unitofwork-associations.html))
- added "remove" in `cascade` option
- changed property mapping in `inversedBy`, reference the property, not the column! (same on the Authentication side)
- Added Authentication type on `$authentication` property (this works in IDE's such as PhpStorm)
- Changed `$userId` property to be the other side of the bi-directional relationship
- Changed `$userId` to `$user` as it will hold a `User` object
- Set up return target mapping instead of column mapping

---

Above I've made it work, but you should have the relation the other way around. Simply because: a User can exist without Authentication, but Authentication cannot exist without a User.

As such, a better relational setup would be:

```
// User class
/**
 * @var Authentication
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\User\Entity\UsersAuthentication", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $authentication;

// Authentication class
/**
 * @var User
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\User\Entity\User", inversedBy="authentication", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $user;
```

This is also shown in the linked bi-directional docs of Doctrine. That example below:

```
/** @Entity */
class Customer
{
    // ...

    /**
     * One Customer has One Cart.
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Cart", mappedBy="customer")
     */
    private $cart;

    // ...
}

/** @Entity */
class Cart
{
    // ...

    /**
     * One Cart has One Customer.
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="cart")
     * @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $customer;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. Adding working scenario in my question now.

Comment: what if I want to update both user and userAuthentication in single query ? How can I do that ?

Comment: You don't make queries. Let Doctrine handle it for you. You just "get" your Entity objects **via the EntityManager** (e.g. in controller `$this->getEntityManager()->getRepository(User::class)->find(2)` (gets user with id 2)). You then make your changes to the User. Then you call `$this->getEntityManager()->persist($user)` followed by `$this->getEntityManager()->flush()`. The `flush()` function handles updating all to-be-updated/created-modified/removed actions to the database.

Comment: Thanks Again. I was actually asking, how can updates be done on both User and UserAuthentication at same time. I get the solution though. It seems like you have good knowledge on zend and doctrine. I am creating an product and may seek your kind guidance. I can pay for that. If it is possible, could you share your email id with me

Comment: If if you get Entity objects via the EntityManager, they're "managed". Doctrine will keep an eye on them via their unique object hashes (under which they're registered internally). Just make your changes to all entities, same as I mentioned. Persist the objects you've changed. Calling the "flush" does the actual work, so call that when you're done changing things. It will then update the DB records with as few queries as possible (so possibly all at once). Have look at [this repo](https://github.com/rkeet/zf-doctrine-form-examples) of mine for additional examples.

Comment: Concerning your offer, I'm not available. Busy with full-time job and some side-projects. The bit of free time that I have I'm going to keep free, because I want to ;) Thank you for the offer though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using unidirectional relation, then in `User` model, you need to set

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\User\Entity\UsersAuthentication", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $authentication;
```

And you need to remove `userId` property in `UsersAuthentication`  entity.